# How to make browser developer tools save HAR file containing untruncated response?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, chromium, httpresponse, har

Sometimes my HTTP responses have rather large content (maybe about 5 MB) and I want to save those together with the rest of the requests in the HAR file. However, the HAR file sometimes only contains part of the response content and sometimes only headers etc but nothing of the content at all. I tried most recent Chrome, Chromium and Firefox browsers.

To reproduce: Open developer tools, record, open a site that returns a large HTTP response (like a big photo JPEG or something) and save the HAR file. It will be much smaller than the size of the JPEG image.

Where is the setting so I can make the developer tool save the full response with the HAR file?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer for Firefox, at least.

This is the bug report, which induces the patch: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1223726 Open `about:config` and change `devtools.netmonitor.responseBodyLimit` from default value `1048576` to your desired size in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

*** Disclaimer: Answer by HttpWatch Developer ***

Our HttpWatch software (Windows only) that works with Chrome and Edge can help you do this. Its default file format (HWL) contains a complete log of all responses whatever their size. The log files can be opened for visual inspection in HttpWatch Studio or examined programmatically using the HttpWatch API.

It can export to HAR files without any restriction on response body size but currently this is only possible using the ExportHAREx automation method:

[https://apihelp.httpwatch.com/HttpWatch_API~HttpWatch.Log~ExportHAREx.html](https://apihelp.httpwatch.com/HttpWatch_API%7EHttpWatch.Log%7EExportHAREx.html)

If you save HAR files directly from the HttpWatch browser extensions response bodies are limited to 50 kB.

You can try HttpWatch for free:

https://www.httpwatch.com/download/

or contact support@neumetrix.com for more information

Comment: I believe there's a hard coded limit in the browser on the size of HAR responses. HttpWatch also presently has a hard coded limit in the GUI tools. Do you need to access the full response bodies programmatically or manually through a GUI tool?